# EF Migrations Error. Design time pattern issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am working on a course that involves ASP.NET Core 2.2 and I am using EF migrations to create a database. All of the necessary entity framework tools have been installed, including the command line tools.

when I attempt to create a code first migration using the command dotnet ef migrations add [Name], I get an error that say this

"Unable to create an object of type 'VegaDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time"

Ive never seen this error before and I was not able to find anyone else who has.

My Configure Services method looks like this.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDbContext<VegaDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));
    }
```

And my DbContext class looks like this

```
public class VegaDbContext : DbContext
{
    public VegaDbContext(DbContextOptions<VegaDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }
}
```

I am running windows 10, on a HP if that helps any.

Comment: Edit*** Now I am getting this error "No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext."

Answer (score 0):

Just type this command on your command line next time you get Design Time error:
* Change databaseName to your Database Name
* Key is to add everything after -s
* Use Window Command line as to VS IDE Command Line

```
dotnet ef dbcontext info -s ..\databaseName\databaseName.csproj
```